# How to change database type and security options in Firebase?

Tags: firebase

Without experience I made few bad decisions when starting with firebase DB in my project. At first I decided to use Cloud Firestore, but after month when I decided to start implement a DB into my project, I want to change into Realtime Database. Somebody can tell mike this option changing it? Because even when I change dropdown pointed by button, is still go back when I go to database options again and I still see Realtime Database selected.
[image]

The second is security options, I decided month ago to use secured mode, now I want change it to test mode without any blockades. But I can't undo my last decision, so how to change it? Now it looks like this:

```
{
    "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking and there is no Firebase product called Cloudstore... there's Cloud Firestore which is a database and the Storage which is where larger files can be stored. There's also the Real Time Data Base which is also a database. There is no direct 'move' from one database to the other - data is specific to the database its stored in and it's unclear if you're trying to move data or just want to use the RTDB. Also, if you've been using Firestore, that *is* a database so why use a different database? Can you clarify the question?

Comment: @Jay from Cloud Firestore to Realtime Database - I fixed it in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

about your question of changing the type of database you are using, create a project in my firebase account by selecting Realtime Database as the database. Later when trying to change the database to Cloud Firestore clicking on the dropdown the following appeared:
[Cloud Firestore Load modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeY1I.png)

Once clicked on accept on the modal, the Cloud Firestore type database is loaded.

About your second question asking for the way to undo the configuration to have an 'open' configuration, it is not necessary since in firebase you can manually change the rules of your project.

In the Rules section of your project, you can directly click on them and modify them:
[Database Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIpi7.png).

I hope my answer has helped you, if you have any questions don't hesitate to ask me.